# OpenStreetMaps routing - starting far from a road

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, php

I am writing an web application, that needs routes between some markers (A, B, C, D).
So far I used the [this api](http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php) with PHP, where I pass each pair of points (A and B, B and C, C and D .... and so on) and loop through each pair to get the coordinates and build polyline. But some of the points are not on the street, like the starting point in [this example](http://openrouteservice.org/index.php?start=27.8388998,43.2264052&end=27.8644022,43.232968&pref=Fastest&lang=bg&noMotorways=false&noTollways=false).

So, technically is there a way to find if any of the points is not on the road?

Comment: Why is it a problem for you if a coordinate is not exactly on a road?

Comment: The route generates dynamically between all the markers. If any of the markers is not on a road, the routing stops nearby the marker on the nearest street. But the outside markers also generate route to that nearest street and it looks awful :) So I need the logic to exclude all the markers not on the street

Answer (score 1):

This requires some work. You can retrieve the nearest road(s) ([ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) with a [highway tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3ahighway)) to some given coordinates using the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). Afterwards you have to check whether your coordinates are on one of the returned roads by comparing them against each [node](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node) and against all segments between *consecutive* nodes of a way.

See this [example Overpass query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/2E5) (using [overpass turbo](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo) for visualizing the result):

```
way
  ["highway"]
  (50.746,7.154,50.747,7.155);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

It returns all ways with a highway tag around the coordinates *50.746, 7.154, 50.747, 7.155* (this is a [bounding box](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bounding_box)) as well as all nodes contained in these ways. Open the *Data* tab to see the raw result.